# How to preserve principal info in Tomcat (i.e. setPrincipal?)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, principal

I'm trying to build a second way for user login alongside the tomcat realm feature. That means an unauthenticated user can either:
1. signing in by evoking realm
2. providing a valid token and getting logged in automatically

I'm trying to achieve 2. So I use a filter to redirect requests into a wrapper. Inside that wrapper I override the `getUserPrincipal` so that a principal for that user can be created. Then the container will recognize the principal and let the user enter without redirecting to the login page.

However now the problem is: it seems that not all requests will get the correct principal. Requests regarding servlet and if the servlet uses `Dispatcher` to forward requests will get principal set. Simple links or servlet using `sendRedirect` will not evoke the `getUserPrincipal` method and thus the login page will appear even if the user is logged in using method 2.

This is just like the principal created for that user is "temporary". I'm wondering if there's a way to store the principal in the session or somewhere so that the container would know that the user is authenticated.

Comment: @Andy: why didn't you create a new tag for Java EE Realm?

Comment: I thought that was more properly the domain of people asking questions in that space and I'd be treading on toes :-) I was cleaning up a bunch of invalid tags - the peril of a company name being a common noun!

Comment: I don't know much about Tomcat or Java EE so don't know what would be a sensible tag name for people in that space - happy to use my high rating to edit again and add a suitable tag if you want to invent one! Should it be tomcat-realm or ee-realm?

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly this but I did it by using the Tomcat JAAS Realm and providing two LoginModules, one for the ticket, and one for username/password. It takes some integrating to prevent getting a login page on a ticket login. Actually in my system there is a third login method, by valid client certificate, and there is a fourth login module, to lookup and assign the roles for the user, however he got established by one of the first three modules.

There is a Google Code project called AuthenticRoast that I have contributed to that helps in this regard. Integrates with both Tomcat 6 and 7, also Glassfish although I haven't tried that.